# Webapplication Layout broke on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, kendo-ui

I tried to make some webpages for mobile devices with kendoUI mobile. On Android an IOS it works properly but then I tried on WP8 and everything was broken. I was not able to spot the problem until now so hopefully someone can help me and tell me where the error is..
Code:

```
<div data-role="drawer" id="my-drawer" style="width: 96%;" data-views="['start']">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-type="group">
        <li>
            <ul>
               <li data-icon="" onclick="colorThis(this)" style="cursor:pointer">One</li>
               <li data-icon="" onclick="colorThis(this)" style="cursor:pointer">Two</li>
               <li data-icon="" onclick="colorThis(this)" style="cursor:pointer">Three</li>
               <li data-icon="" onclick="colorThis(this)" style="cursor:pointer">Four</li>
               <li data-icon="" onclick="colorThis(this)" style="cursor:pointer">Five</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
               <li data-icon="" style="cursor:pointer" id ="" onclick="colorThis(this)">Six</li>
               <li data-icon="" style="cursor:pointer" id ="" onclick="colorThis(this)">Seven</li>
               <li data-icon="" style="cursor:pointer" id ="" onclick="colorThis(this)">Eight</li>
               <li data-icon="" style="cursor:pointer" id ="" onclick="colorThis(this)">Nine</li>
               <li data-icon="" style="cursor:pointer" id ="" onclick="colorThis(this)">Ten</li>
               <li data-icon="" style="cursor:pointer" id ="" onclick="colorThis(this)">Eleven</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="layout" data-id="drawer-layout">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#my-drawer" data-icon="search" data-align="left"></a>
            <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            <a data-align="right" data-role="button" class="nav-button" data-rel="external" data-icon="home" href="home.aspx"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id = "start" runat="server" data-title="Aufgaben" data-role="view" data-layout="drawer-layout" style="">
        <div id="maindiv" data-role="page" style="display:block; text-align:center; height:100%" >
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID ="lbl_editorInfo" Text=""></asp:Label><br /><br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID ="lbl_taskStatus" Text="success"></asp:Label>
            <div style="width:99%"><input type="text" ID="search_txt" runat="server" class="km-text full" /></div><br />
            <ul id="taskList" style="width:99%"></ul>
        </div>
        <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
            <div id="div_templ" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="" >
                <div style="overflow:hidden; margin-top:5px; text-overflow:ellipsis; ">
                    <span class="" style="width:25%"></span><span class="" style="" title=""></span>
                </div>
                <div style="overflow:hidden; margin-top:2px; text-overflow:ellipsis;" >
                    <span class="" style="width:25%"></span><span class="" style="" title=""></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both" ></div>
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport:
            {
                read:
                {
                    url: url,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
                schema:
            {
                data: 'GetDATAResult.RootResults',
                total: 'GetDATAResult.TotalCount'
            },
                pageSize: 10,
                serverPaging: true
            });

            function checkTheBox(chkBoxID) {
                var theBox = document.getElementById(chkBoxID);
                if (theBox.checked) {
                    theBox.checked = false;
                }
                else {
                    theBox.checked = true;
                }
                colorThis(theBox);
            }

            function colorThis(t) {
                if (!($(t).hasClass("background_orange"))) {
                    $(t).addClass("background_orange");
                }
                else {
                    $(t).removeClass("background_orange");
                }
            }

            $("#taskList").kendoMobileListView({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                template: $("#template").text()

            });

            var app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body),
            {
                loading: "<h1>Loading...</h1>"
            });
        </script>
```

On the WP theres only the plain html, no style or javascript from kendoUI.

Greetings,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. Have you been able to find anything?

On Preliminary investigation, seems like the IE browser in WP8 actively blocks the callback that it receives. Some information on this behaviour can be found here: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/27/ie9-beta-google-image-search-javascript-content-type-and-nosniff.aspx

Also, if you create a JSBin of your datasource, you can inspect the error in the IE Browser Developer Tools Window -> Console: 
Script from  was blocked due to mime type mismatch

Sorry, I still don't have any resolution for this. I have just shared some findings.